# TypeScript dont check React props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I started migrate my React project to TypeScript and need little help. When i compile test component props checking not working.

TypeScript 2.1.4

Component.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

interface IPlayProps {
    status: string,
    addClass: string
}

class Play extends React.Component<IPlayProps, any> {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>{this.props.addClass}</div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Play addClass={0} />,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "sourceMap": false,
    "allowJs": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "outDir": "./compiled/"
  },
  "include": [
    "resources/scripts/player/globals.d.ts",
    "resources/scripts/player/components/footer/Play.tsx"
  ]
}
```

typings.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "registry:npm/react#15.0.1+20160601175240",
    "react-dom": "registry:npm/react-dom#15.0.1+20160826174104"
  },
  "globalDependencies": {
    "file-saver": "registry:dt/file-saver#0.0.0+20161106021201",
    "jquery": "registry:dt/jquery#1.10.0+20161119044246",
    "underscore": "registry:dt/underscore#1.8.3+20161123125004",
    "x2js": "registry:dt/x2js#0.0.0+20160510002910"
  }
}
```

globals.d.ts

```
/// <reference path="../../../typings/main.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../../../typings/index.d.ts" />
```

Render component with wrong prop type

```
<Play addClass={0} />
```

and no errors in terminal, why?

Comment: I see that you have react typings installed, but are they included properly ? check - https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html

Comment: If you're using typescript 2 then you better use [@types](https://www.npmjs.com/~types) instead of typings, it's more straight forward and works much better. Also, what console are you talking about?

Comment: @shershen, yes I read typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html and take last example for base

Comment: @shershen Added globals.d.ts content to question. Without this file project cant compile

Comment: @NitzanTomer, tnx! With types and typescript 2.2.0-dev.20161225 it works! Only one thing, PHPStorm cant resolve react module anymore :(. I will continue to dig, thank you very much!

Comment: @types work with 2.1.4 so there was no need to update to a dev version. Do you have a current version of phpstorm? I've never used that, but with webstorm it works like a charm.

Comment: @NitzanTomer, without latest TS I catch this problem https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12724. I cant update phpstorm right now with my current license. I made this "hack": types for tsc, typings for IDE. All works fine.

Comment: That will become hard to manage, also you can by mistake have different versions in the two folders